# Why is System.Transactions.TransactionOptions a mutable struct

Tags: .net, transactionscope

Given that most people think that [mutable structs are not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil) ("evil" is too absolute for me), why is `System.Transactions.TransactionOptions` a mutable struct rather than being either an immutable struct or a class?

And why doesn't it have a constructor that takes `isolationLevel` and `timeout` arguments?

I must say I find it non-intuitive to have to create an instance of the struct and set its properties before passing it to a `TransactionScope` constructor.

Comment: IMO it's mutating methods that are the problem with structs. Fields and properties are relatively harmless.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - I don't understand what you mean.  Why would mutations via methods be more problematic than those via properties?

Comment: The big problem with mutable structs is that you might mutate an unexpected copy. With properties/fields you can't call the setter on temporary values (what c++'s call rvalue). But you can call mutating methods on those values without an error. So the biggest error source is eliminated if you don't have mutating methods. I wouldn't have made `TransactionOptions` mutable, but mutable structs aren't as bad as many claim.